# How can I check (through Haskell) is the DLL file managed?

Tags: .net, haskell, dll

Directory contains DLL files. Some of them are *native*, but some of them are *managed* (i.e. .NET assemblies). I need to get all managed DLL files. How can I check (*through Haskell*) is the DLL file managed?

Comment: General direction: parse the PE header and check if it uses any CLR libraries (they usually go as "mscor*.dll"). Hmm, however I suppose a dll could use it if it wanted without being managed, it should be extremely rare however.